# Curly Brackets after if condition

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

In powershell we faced a peculiar issue where a statement worked on a system and not on another

```
if (condition)
    DoSomething
```

> Missing statement block after if ( condition )

I know I can fix by adding curly braces `{ DoSomething }` but I need to find why this happened. Is it a Powershell syntax upgrade which worked on one and not on another?

PS version where it worked

[image]

Comment: AFAIK wrapping a statement block in braces has never been optional in *any* version. Certainly neither `powershell -version 2` or `powershell -version 3` allow this, but I haven't tested with a vanilla PS 3 install since I no longer have one. If you have the exact statement that's supposed to have been working, that might shed some light on it (it could be a peculiar parsing).

Comment: What Jeroen said. Can you reproduce the behavior by running something like `if ($true) Write-Output 'foo'` in a PowerShell console launched from CMD via `powershell.exe -NoProfile` on the host where that supposedly had worked?

Answer (score 1):

I tried to replicate this but wasn't able to in any of my Windows boxes, Windows 7, 8.1 and latest 10 (1803).

However, personally, I consider writing code like

```
if(condition)
    Statement
```

to be bad practice.

Imagine what happens if you would comment out that `Statement`.

```
if(condition)
    //Statement
OtherStatement
```

If you are not careful you could potentially have the `if` statement target some entirely different code, that you didn't intend to, and this way introduce a bug.

If you absolutely need to have a an `if` statement without curly brackets, then

```
if(condition) Statement
```

would be cleaner and less error-prone. However, I still prefer to always use `{` and `}` in any conditional statement.